# Rust rayon crate par_iter().map() "stalls" when saving images

Tags: rust, rayon

I'm trying to learn Rust from an example on [data-parallelism](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/concurrency/parallel.html#generate-jpg-thumbnails-in-parallel) in this linked rust-cookbook example.

However, when I run the code (with what I believe are the correct dependencies), the parallel iterator functions do not complete. [This is the exact repo](https://github.com/JacobSNGoodwin/data-parallelism) I am struggling with.

When I run `cargo run` at the root of the project containing 5 images, I get the following in the console.

```sh
Current number threads: 4
Saving 5 thumbnails into 'thumbnails'...
```

However, none of the thumbnails are created, and the program never exits. The code compiles.

I have the same problem in another [little CLI](https://github.com/JacobSNGoodwin/image-variants) I'm working on to try to learn Rust, but I think the example from the cookbook is easier to work with.

Any tips, even with what I might look for, would be greatly appreciated. I wonder if it is machine relating.

Comment: Can you share a small minimal re-producible example of your code here so we can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known deadlock bug in the `image` crate's JPEG decoder: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/image-rs/jpeg-decoder/issues/227)

The JPEG decoding itself makes use of rayon internally by default, and when you use rayon yourself to decode several JPEGs at once, this bug is triggered. As a workaround, you can stop the JPEG decoder from using rayon by specifying the `image` crate dependency in `Cargo.toml` like this:

```
image = { version = "0.24.1", default-features = false, features = ["jpeg"] }
```

That disables the `image` crate's default features, one of which is `jpeg_rayon`.

Comment: Awesome! I thought it might be something internal to image. I really appreciate your knowledge and saving me digging through (potentially) many issues.